# Aplicação Web para monitoramento de scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Qual a melhor maneira de monitorar a execução de um script?
Tenho um script.py que precisa ficar rodando "infinitamente", e gostaria de saber se ele esta sendo executado ou não.
Gostaria de uma aplicação web para fazer esse monitoramento, e caso ele feche, eu consiga executa-lo atraves dessa aplicação.
Existe alguma freamework que faça algo parecido?

Comment: Em suma, você precisa de um serviço. Isso de aplicação web para disparar um script que deve ter ciclo de vida próprio e independente é um tanto quanto gambiarra. Parece-me que está a [quebrar cocos usando canhões](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6585/64969)

Comment: exato, vou tranformar esse script em um serviço. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), nele é tudo muito simples e facil para fazer uma aplicação web. Com o Django você cria sua interface web para monitorar e ativar o script.

O Django já tem um sistema de autenticação embutido entao você pode criar uma interface segura sem trabalho.

Com a seu webapp pronto, dentro do loop do seu script você pode chamar um metodo/função que envia um POST para o webapp "dizendo que está tudo bem"

Caso você queria um processo 100% automatico junto com o Django você pode usar o Celery e criar tarefas periodicas que verifica se o script está enviando o "esta tudo bem" caso não esteja você automaticamente configura para reexecutar o script.

Você pode até avancar mais e usar os bancos de dados para gravar logs etc.

Comment: Bom, a sua ideia  de usar uma tarefa no celery para verificar se estar rodando ou não abriu minha mente, obrigado kk. Usar o Django que eu acho que não é viavel estou pensando em usar um microframework mesmo, tipo o Flask

Comment: Para mim o django e natural e pratico, gosto do flask mas e que o django já esta tudo pronto sem dor ahaha. Mas o flask é bom e simples use ele.